# How to fill cells based on complicated formula?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a complicated formula. What I'm looking to do is to set it up where if column A is YR then column B-J will highlight red if the date is more than 2 years ago and yellow if the date is within 30 days of reaching the 2 year mark.

If column A is P1, P2, P3, P4, or P5 then column B-J will highlight red if the date is more than 1 year ago and yellow if its within 30 days of reaching the one year mark.

Comment: You mention *the date*. Where is that?

Comment: I tried adding an image, however I don't have enough reputation just yet. All the dates are different. It's pretty much a worksheet that tracks training dates for about 150 individuals. I'm just trying to set it up to where it highlights red if it's past due and yellow when coming due.

Comment: Ok, but where are they? :) Are they in the B-J cells? Your question doesn't really say.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, yes they are in cells B-J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create two conditional formatting rules. First select B2:J6 (as laid out in the image below, the bottom row will vary with your own data) with B2 as the `Active Cell`. Create a new formula using the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and supply the following for *Format values where this formula is true:*

```
=AND(OR($A2="P1",$A2="P2",$A2="P3",$A2="P4",$A2="P5",$A2="YR"),B2<=EDATE(TODAY(),(1+($A2="YR"))*-12))
```

Click Format and supply a red *Fill*. I also added a white *Font* for readability. Click OK to accept the format and then OK again to create the new rule.

With B2:J6 still selected, repeat with the following formula for a yellow fill.

```
=AND(OR($A2="P1",$A2="P2",$A2="P3",$A2="P4",$A2="P5",$A2="YR"),B2>EDATE(TODAY(),(1+($A2="YR"))*-12),B2<=(EDATE(TODAY(),(1+($A2="YR"))*-12)+30))
```

You results should be similar to the following.

[image]