# Conditional Formatting for many different values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function, excel-match

I've been trying to create a conditional format formula that looks in a column and finds a series of names and colors them the same color. I want to get this done with one formula instead of a bunch of formulae.
[image]

I have tried INDIRECT, VLOOKUP and to work with a statement from [How to fill cells based on complicated formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902350/how-to-fill-cells-based-on-complicated-formula). I'd like something like this: [Excel dynamic conditional formatting based on cell version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158746/excel-dynamic-conditional-formatting-based-on-cell-version-2)  but am having trouble converting it to text instead of date.

Comment: Could you provide an _exact_ example of what the sheet would look like with the conditional formatting?  Those 2 questions are _very_ different and makes it unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: does that picture make sense?  so like a conditional statement for text contains almost but with multiple names

Comment: Not entirely.  So are your 2 search strings _dan_ and _frank joe sarah_?  And if so why is _mark_ highlighted?

Comment: sorry the picture is what I want but I have highlighted them manually to show proof of concept.

Comment: I understand it is a proof of concept, you did well showing your _desired result_ but what is your _input_?  What exactly does `B dan : color red frank joe sarah : color red cliff` mean?  Are your inputs _dan, frank, joe, sarah_?

Comment: I think I see, after looking back at the edits you had line breaks, if you want your question formatted with line breaks and such you can highlight the text and click on the **`{}`** button to keep the formatting properly.  However I am still wondering why the `sarah vs mark`

Comment: sorry that input I typed out was my attempt to show you what the cells looked like before I saw I could insert an image.

Comment: chancea thank you so much for all your rapid responses. im so sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two lists of names, say in ColumnA and ColumnI, and wish to highlight those in A that feature in I please select columnA and try applying a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
  =MATCH(A1,I:I,0)>0
```

Comment: that works out great! all I have to do is just hide a column with the names I want.